# SQL - Returning Each Record Only Once

Tags: sql, tags

Here's my tables:

```
tblBusiness
BusinessID, BusinessName

tblTags
TagID, Tag

tblBusinessTagLink
BusinessID, TagID
```

Any business can have multiple tags applied to it. Now lets say a user is filtering down so that they find only businesses that are tagged 'Office Supplies' and 'Technology'

What SQL statement should I use? Is there a better design for my tables than what I've presented here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  b.BusinessId,
  b.BusinessName 
FROM
  tblBusiness AS b
  INNER JOIN tblBusinessTagLink AS l ON l.BusinessId = b.BusinessId
  INNER JOIN tblTags            AS t ON t.TagId      = l.TagId
WHERE
  t.TagName IN ('Technology', 'Office Supplies')
GROUP BY
  b.BusinessId,
  b.BusinessName
```

This selects all businesses that are in either one of the categories. To select only those in both categories, you could append a

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

The method you are using (three tables to represent a m:n relationship) is the standard way to solve this task, you can keep that.

Personally, I would not use "hungarian notation" for table names (i.e. no "tbl") and I would not use plural table names (i.e. not "Tags"), especially when the other tables are not plural either.

---

*Answering the first comment below:*

For larger data sets, the performance of this query relies on indexes. All the primary keys need an index, naturally. In `tblBusinessTagLink` you should have a composite index covering both fields and one additional index for the field that does not come first in the composite index.

The `WHERE keywords LIKE '%technology%'` idea is a bad one, mostly because for any LIKE conditions other than start-of-field searches an index cannot be used (i.e. performance will degrade rapidly as your data set grows) and partly because it should be `WHERE ','+keywords+',' LIKE '%,technology,%'` to begin with or you will get partial matches/false positives.

Also, it might be a bit more efficient to query by `TagId`. This way you can remove one table from the JOIN entirely:

```
FROM 
  tblBusiness AS b 
  INNER JOIN tblBusinessTagLink AS l ON l.BusinessId = b.BusinessId 
WHERE 
  l.TagId IN (1, 2)
```

If you intend to query by `TagName` however, an index on this field will be absolutely necessary as well.

Comment: thanks for the notes on hungarian notation and plural names. I'm still trying to undo all the things I learned while building Access databases. Will the performance of this query go down as the quantity of business entries increase? Or as the quantity of tags selected increases? Or both? I plan to give users the option to select records that have as many as five or six tags applied to them. Sometimes I wonder if it wouldn't be faster to take the tags and store them in a keywords field so I could Select b.BusinessID, b.BusinessName from tblBusiness WHERE keywords like '%technology%' and...

Comment: See additional comments in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple JOIN to get record

```
SELECT t.Tag, b.BusinessName 
FROM tblBusiness b, tblTags t, tblBusinessTagLink l
WHERE t.TagID = l.TagID 
AND l.BusinessID = b.BusinessID 
AND t.Tag = 'Office Supplies'
```

Comment: I'm not understanding a few things. Is "t" and "b" your table names? Where is the join statement or does this sql statement not need a join? Also, you didn't specify the tag 'Technology'.

Comment: I modified it and it to try to return the correct record(s) if two categories are chosen and I get no results in my query. SELECT t.Tag, b.BusinessName
FROM tblBusiness AS b, tblTags AS t, tblBusinessTagLink AS l
WHERE (t.Tag = 'Office Supplies' AND t.TagID = [l].[TagID] AND l.BusinessID = [b].[BusinessID]) AND
(t.Tag = 'Technology' AND t.TagID = [l].[TagID] AND l.BusinessID = [b].[BusinessID]);

Comment: why not using ANSI join syntax?

Comment: -1 for implicit join structure. It works, but it is a horrible way to code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [INTERSECT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#INTERSECT_operator) set operation to merge the 2 queries (one for 'Office Supplies' and one for 'Technology').

However if you are using MySQL (which does not support INTERSECT), you can use a UNION ALL with a 'HAVING COUNT(*) = 2' [like this](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/175196).

---

EDIT:

You can also use the second option without the UNION ALL like so:

```
select Name from tblBusiness
left join tblBusinessTagLink on tblBusinessTagLink.BusinessID = tblBusiness.ID
left join tblTags on tblTags.TagID = tblBusinessTagLink.TagID
where Tag = 'Office Supplies' or Tag = 'Technology'
group by name
having count(Name) = 2;
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if your solution is the same as Tomalak's. How would you do this if the user wanted to apply 3 or 4 tags at once using "AND" instead of "OR"?

Comment: I believe both Tomalak's and my solution are the same (however I highly recommend benchmarking between his 'where x in (y, z)' and my 'where x = y or x = z'). You should also be aware that if a single Business has the same Tag twice neither will work correctly.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I think I'll take steps to prevent a user from entering the same tag twice.